# Kendo Sortable - Leave item in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am playing with using a Kendo Sortable.  I would like to drag an item from one list in order to populate another, but I need to leave that item in the original list.  Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to sortable might be draggable & dropTarget.

Have a look at [Moving items from one list to another](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/draganddrop/overview#moving-items-from-one-list-to-another).

```
$("#listB").kendoDropTarget({
    dragenter: addStyling,
    dragleave: resetStyling,
    drop: function(e) { //apply changes to the data after an item is dropped
        var draggableElement = e.draggable.currentTarget,
        dataItem = listA_DS.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid")); //find the corresponding dataItem by uid


        //--- Change --- listA_DS.remove(dataItem); //remove the item from ListA
        listB_DS.add(dataItem); //add the item to ListB

        resetStyling.call(this); //reset visual dropTarget indication that was added on dragenter
    }
});
```

[Modified Example from that page](http://dojo.telerik.com/ecIha/8)

Comment: Thank you Johan.  It was right in front of my face and I didn't notice it.  Zone in on something on the blinders go on.  :-/